# Django view gets called twice... sometimes

Tags: python, django, http, request

I have several logging.debug statements in the home view of a web site, mainly to log the start time and the end time of a bunch of sql queries.

However, sometimes, I see those sets of debug statements pop up twice in a row in the debug log. Of course, during that time only one user has made ONE request (as in refresh, hit enter, etc.)

Any ideas on what might cause this? We think this may be related to another problem we're having.

Comment: Could you add some log excerpts? Perhaps from the web server request log as well, if you've got one.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your view function is called once, but you are logging twice.  I've had problems before where my logging add_handler call was being run twice, so the log had the same handler twice, so one log.debug() call would result in the same message in the log twice.